# How to initialize a parameter with 0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this simple input

```
 // I loop this input  many times so it generates a lot of inputs with different index
 <input value='0' type='number' [(ngModel)]="clients.clientInputs[idx]"/>
```

And this simple class

```
export class Clients {
  clientInputs = [];
}
```

in my ts file

```
  clients:Clients = new Clients();
```

**The problem is that they override the default value of 0 with null. How do I initialize everything in that array with 0?**

This question comes from the answer to my previous question: [Very Simple usage of ngModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490411/very-simple-usage-of-ngmodel)

Comment: Use push. Function so every output will be save in array . But 1st create array with 1st value 0.  clientInputs.push(value to send);

Comment: When you've finished looping through your inputs, you could use `array.fill()`.

Comment: I mean that the user sees a input html but with empty instead of 0. I want them to see the default value of 0

Comment: That's not quite what you asked.

Comment: User schould see default value when?  Before he puts something or after he send form?

Comment: change it to `clientInputs = Array(1).fill(0);`  (An array with 1 element that has a value of 0)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)  which 'fills' all the elements of an array.

example:

`Array(5).fill(0) // output: [0,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: Nice solution, didn't know about that fill method.

Comment: `this.clients.clientInputs = Array( this.clients.clientTypes.length).fill(0);` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand what you have, you have one input per client type so you can do a loop for the client types and initialize each client type input in the array as 0 as following:

```
for (let index = 0; index < clientTypes.length; index++) {
   this.clientTypesInputs[index] = 0; 
}
```

Comment: I think they just want an array with 1 value of 0 in it.

Comment: i think this is what I want but where do I put this?

Comment: Solution form @fabien is cleaner, you can put that in the ngOnInit method.